# Change the Link function in this Button script

Tags: javascript, button, hyperlink, mouseover

Hi I am new here perhaps some one can help me. 
Is it possible to change this Button javascript so that the linked page opens with out it being in a new window?

**Head**

```
<style>

.thisclass{background-color:transparent}

</style>
<script language="javascript">

function change(color){
var el=event.srcElement
if (el.tagName=="INPUT"&&el.type=="button")
event.srcElement.style.backgroundColor=color
}

function jumpto2(url){
window.location=url
}
</script>
```

**Body**

```
<form onMouseOver="change('transparent')" onMouseOut="change('transparent')"><p>
<input type="button" name="Button" class="thisclass" value="Ken Videos" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#0000FF'" 
onMouseOut="this.style.color='#000000'" onMouseDown="this.style.color='#FFFFFF'" style="color: #000000; font-family: 
Arial; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12pt; width: 156; height: 30; border: 4px double #FFFFFF" onClick="fenster=window.open('ger_mitglieder-videos-ken.htm', 
'fenster','toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,width=900,height=650, left = 50, top = 100')"></p>
</form>
```